# Images won't show in firefox using content:url

Tags: css, image, firefox

I've been looking for an answer for 3 days straight now (i did sleep a few hours though).

I'm using a wordpress theme that integrates font awesome icons smoothly. But i wanted to alter these icons and use my own, but they won't show in Firefox but do show in Safari, Chrome etc.

I'm using this css code to alter the icon to my own icons:

```
.fa-euro:before {content:url(http://nip10.nl/xtra-icons/icon-2.png);}
.fa-glass:before {content:url(http://nip10.nl/xtra-icons/icon-1.png);}
.fa-bell:before {content:url(http://nip10.nl/xtra-icons/icon-3.png);}
.fa-coffee:before {content:url(http://nip10.nl/xtra-icons/icon-4.png);}
```

You can see the website here: www.nip10.nl

Hope someone can tell me how i can alter the css code so the icons also show in FireFox.. I've tried anything from naming images to .jpg files etc. etc..

Comment: Have you tried using `fa-euro::before {content:url(http://nip10.nl/xtra-icons/icon-2.png);}`.?
Double colons that is.

Comment: Hi Jimmy thanks for replying, i'm about to try this out now :-$

Comment: Nope that didn't do the trick unfortunetely

Answer (score 1):

You should validate your HTML. See here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nip10.nl

I'm going to guess that the problem is that firefox is running into this error

> Line 1069, Column 26: Element style not allowed as child of element
>   div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

And failing to parse the embedded style sheet.  You should also not embed your large stylesheets like that.  Make them external style sheets.  Once that's done, find where your HTML error is that's causing the validator to think you don't have the style sheet in the head tag and it should fix itself.

Comment: Hi Joseph thank you so much for taking the time to reply and look into my problem ! I've did the validation just now and your are right it is showing the error you are mentioning above..

I'm not sure what you mean with embed a large stylesheet and make them external stylesheets, i get a little lost after what to do after the validation :-( sorry! I know my way around in html and css and a tiny bit of php but im mostly great in customizing wordpress themes.. ;-)

Comment: @user1084321 What I'm referring to is instead of using a stylesheet like this: `<style type="text/css"> ... </style>`.  You should move the styles to a file and save it with the extension `.css`.  Then you can link to it using something like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/whatnot/css/styles.css" type="text/css">` (url can be wherever you decide to put the file).  Although I recommend this method the real problem is that there is probably a missing tag somewhere in the code.  You don't necessarily have to move the style sheet.